# Wordpress permalinks set

Tags: wordpress

How can I pass category ID using permalinks?
my post page id is 205 and for that I used function `<?php echo get_page_link('205');?>` and I also want to pass category id along with this link, how can I pass category Id with this page link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "passing category id". I'm just guessing you want to extract the (first) category id for a post with a specifik post id, if so you could try:

```
<?php echo (get_the_category('205')[0]->cat_ID; ?>
```